# Spring request Mapping and themes

Tags: java, spring-mvc, themes

I have a problem with Spring 3.0.7 Request mapping and the Spring standard theme implementation.

My controllers are implemented  as follows

```
@ Controller
@RequestMapping(value="myUrl")
Public MyControllerClass

 @RequestMapping(Method=requestMethod.GET)
 Public myGetHandler (){
 }
```

So a URL with http://myApp/myUrl is handled and all is good.

Themes are activated by a link link this

```
 <a href="?theme=mytheme"/>
```

and the spring config for themes is

```
<bean id="themeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="theme" />
</bean>
```

So if I am on the myUrl page and I click this link the theme is loaded and myGetHandler also invoked.

however

if I add a parameter to my URL

```
 /myUrl?someParm=somevalue
```

now my controller works as before and i can access the parameter but clicking on the themes link ( see href above ) which for this page looks like this

```
/myUrl?theme=myTheme
```

causes an exception and neither the page or the theme load. I will post the stack trace later but it suggested a problem in the controller ( and not theme interceptor ).

How can I map my controller so that themes and a parameterized URL work? Ideally I think I want to change my request mapping to only handle my parameterized url and nothing else ?

I tried changing my request mapping to

```
   @RequestMapping(value="myUrl",params = "someParam=someValue")
```

While this works for the links with my parameters it fails for the theme link.

Comment: It would help if you elaborated on "clicking on the themes link causes a crash". What's the URL of the link? And what happens when you click it? Post the complete stack trace, and the relevant code if the exception occurs in your code.

Comment: Clarified the error condition. I will post the stack trace later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is then in case when url is with params , click on `<a href="?theme=mytheme"/>` casues double "?" in destination url like   `/myUrl?someParm=somevalue?theme=mytheme`.

You should use something like c:url or some javascript to build url with only one ? and & as params delimeter

Comment: the theme url is specified by spring. I can't change it . It is intercepted by the theme interceptor. I will check the debug log and confirm but it appears that when the theme interceptor fires it "refires" the existing URL